# How to become the arrow segment smoother in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-curve

This is my plot:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg))+geom_point()+ geom_curve(aes(y = 18, yend = 15, x = 4, xend = 3.75), arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.1, "cm"), type = 'closed'),curvature = -0.85, color = '#e91d82', lineend = 'round')
```

The arrow is not 'smooth' there are some 'breaks' (I dont know if this is the right word). How can I have a smoother arrow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make curve smoother You can use argument `ncp` (the number of control points used to draw the curve), however the arrow will not be perfectly smooth anyway.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg))+geom_point()+ 
  geom_curve(aes(x = 4, xend = 3.75, y = 18, yend = 15), arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.02, "npc"), type = 'closed'),curvature = -0.85, color = '#e91d82', ncp = 1000)
```

[image]